# Filter Unicode characters in character array

Tags: c++, unicode-string

I have character array which may or may not contain Unicode characters. When present, it will be a mixture of Unicode and ASCII characters. I need to find a way to filter out Unicode characters while traversing the string char by char.

And I need to do everything in C++.

Comment: The question is a bit vague; unicode can be encoded in different ways. What exactly do you mean by _normal_ characters; _ASCII_? Some encodings, like [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8), contain _ASCII_ as a subset, so it will we impossible to filter these.

Comment: You forgot to ask a specific answerable question, and describe how it resisted your attempts to solve it.

Answer (score 2):

This is impossible in general. A character is just a number. It does not carry information about its encoding.

Consider an analogy: A number value does not carry information about the unit. If a space ship moves at the speed of 0.5, how long does it take to travel a kilometer? It depends on the unit. Is it 0.5 meters per second? Or is it 0.5 times the speed of light? You cannot tell from the number.

Similarly, what character does the value 76 represent? You cannot know, unless you know the encoding. If the encoding is UTF-8, then it represents `'L'`. If the encoding is EBCDIC, then it represents `'<'`. So, is 76 a Unocide `'L'` that you are supposed to filter, or is it an EBCDIC `'<'` that you're not supposed to filter?

You cannot tell from a value what encoding it is in. However, you can in some cases determine that a value is not in a particular encoding. For example, ASCII is a 7-bit encoding, so you know that any (unsigned) number greater than 127 can not be in ASCII.

So, if you have a mix of ASCII and Unicode, then you can determine that values greater than 127 are Unicode, and other values are either Unicode or ASCII. In fact, the other values are both Unicode *and* ASCII simultaneously, because the first 127 code points of Unicode have the same mapping as ASCII by design.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, it's important to know the particular Unicode *encoding* that is used in the character array. Since you referred to `char` in your question, I assume your *"character"* array is a `char` array, so it's very likely that you are using **[UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8)** as the Unicode encoding.

One of the [nice properties of UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Advantages) is that ASCII is a proper subset of it. So, you can simply scan the whole `char` array. If the current `char` has its high-order bit cleared (i.e. equal `0`, or equivalently the byte value is `<= 127`), then this is a pure (7-bit) ASCII character, and you accept it. Else, this `char` is part of a multi-byte UTF-8 sequence, and you can skip it and move to the next `char` in the array, and repeat.

Answer (score 1):

Eihter the code is in a wdie byte format, or it is is UTF-8. The logic is the same in either case.

ASCII codes are in the range 0-127.

```
int j = 0;
int i;

for(i=0;i<Len;i++)
  if(unicode[i] >= 0 && unicode[i] <=127)
     unicode[j++] = unicode[i];
```

If the format is UTF-8 it's just the same code, but you will be skipping over several characters with the high bit set for each extended character.
You you want 8 bit char *ascii, you must of course assign to an ascii buffer rather than keeping the data in the Unicode buffer.

Comment: I wonder if the statement should be like: `unicode_filtered[j++]=unicode[i];`, I mean storing filtered values in a new array.